# Google Cloud Storage with PHP: Error ' (403) Access Not Configured'

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-storage

I'm making a simple request using the following code sample below.
It seems I'm not the only one getting this error, and I haven't been able to find any solutions. It seems self explanatory, but how is it solved?

This is the exact error I'm getting:

> Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/eggs: (403) Access Not Configured

And The Code:

```
require_once 'google/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google/src/contrib/Google_StorageService.php';

define("CLIENT_ID", 'hidden');
define("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME", 'hidden');
define("KEY_FILE", 'hidden.p12');

define("PROJECT_ID", hidden);

$client = new Google_Client();
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);


$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
                array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'),
                $key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);


$storageService = new Google_StorageService($client);
try 
{
   $bucket = $storageService->buckets->get('hidden');


}      
catch (exception $e)
{
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```